# The left operand of '>' is a garbage value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When i build and anylayse my app , i get the below memeory warning

> "The left operand of '>' is a garbage value" at this line isTrue = (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;

What is the problem over here.Thanks for any help

```
 (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength;
    BOOL isTrue;
    if(textField == txtFirstName){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        //isTrue = (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;
    }
    if(textField == txtLastName){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        //isTrue = (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;
    }
    if(textField == txtEmail){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        //isTrue =  (newLength > 100) ? NO : YES;
    }
    if(textField == txtCompanyName){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        //isTrue =  (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
    }
    if(textField == txtPassword){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        //isTrue =  (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
    }
    if(textField == txtRe_EnterPassword){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        //isTrue =  (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
    }
    if(textField == txtZipCode){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        //isTrue =  (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;
    }
    if(textField == txtCountry){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        //isTrue =  (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
    }
    isTrue = (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;

    return isTrue;
}
```

Comment: You can replace the whole method with one line: return ([textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length <= 20);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem occurs when all of the if conditions fail, ie. if `textField` is not one of the set you are expecting it to be.

In this case, `newLength` is never assigned to, and will be a random garbage value.
Whilst this is probably "never going to happen", the static analyzer is not aware of that.

You should initialize `newLength` to have a default value, perhaps zero.

Answer (score 1):

the analyzer cannot confirm that your 'switch-like construct' does not 'fall through'. `newLength`'s value may never be set if all those *if* cases fail. then in that event, it *would* qualify as a garbage value.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes to your code I think now it would be work better.

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = 0;
    BOOL isTrue = false;

    if(textField == txtFirstName){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        isTrue = (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else if(textField == txtLastName){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        isTrue = (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else if(textField == txtEmail){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        isTrue =  (newLength > 100) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else if(textField == txtCompanyName){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        isTrue =  (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else if(textField == txtPassword){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        isTrue =  (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else if(textField == txtRe_EnterPassword){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        isTrue =  (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else if(textField == txtZipCode){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        isTrue =  (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else if(textField == txtCountry){
        newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        isTrue =  (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else {
        isTrue = (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;
    }

    return isTrue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be correct, if (at least) one of your if tests is always guaranteed to pass. But the analyzer cannot determine that. If you can convince yourself of that, you can ignore the warning.

But a better idea would be to change those into else ifs, and put one last else, inside which is an NSAssert.

Answer (score 0):

Try
[a compare:b] returns -1 if a < b, 0 if a == b and 1 if a > b.

isTrue =  ([newLength compare:20]==1) ? NO : YES;